# confusion on which serializer to use to update user profile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a profile model for user to update. I want to have a rest api for that. I have a profile model which is too big than usual. I am working to update the user profile but I am having confusion on which serializer should i use to update the profile. Here is what i have done till now

I created the serializer for user and user profile.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'user','current_location', 'permanent_location', 'dob',
                    'about_me', 'gender_status', 'create_profile_for', 'marital_status',
                    'height', 'weight', 'body_type', 'complexion',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)
  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('id', 'profile', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      # instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(validated_data)
      profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
      #updating user data
      instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
      instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
      instance.email = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.email)
      #updating profile data
      if not instance.profile:
          Profile.objects.create(user=instance, **profile_data)
      instance.profile.current_location = profile_data.get('current_location', instance.profile.current_location)
      instance.profile.permanent_location = profile_data.get('permanent_location', instance.profile.permanent_location)
      instance.profile.weight = profile_data.get('weight', instance.profile.weight)
      instance.profile.height = profile_data.get('height', instance.profile.height)
      instance.profile.about_me = profile_data.get('about_me', instance.profile.about_me)
      instance.profile.create_profile_for = profile_data.get('create_profile_for', instance.profile.create_profile_for)
      instance.profile.body_type = profile_data.get('body_type', instance.profile.body_type)
      instance.save()
      return instance
```

This is my view

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
        Returns a list of profile of user
        """
        reply={}
        try:
            profile_instance = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            if token:
                profile = profile_instance.get(token=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile_instance, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data']=[]
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
        update a profile
        """
        profile=None
        if not token is None:
            try:
                profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user, token=token)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
            except:
                return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        reply={}
        if not serialized_data.is_valid():
            return error.ValidationError(serialized_data.errors).as_response()
        else:
            profile = serialized_data.save(user=request.user)
            reply['data']=self.serializer_class(profile, many=False).data
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How should i handle my user profile update?

Updated my UserSerializer with update function

UPDATE with Dean Christian Armada solution

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
        Returns a list of profile of user
        """
        reply={}
        try:
            profile_instance = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            if token:
                profile = profile_instance.get(token=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile_instance, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data']=[]
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, token=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        update a profile
        """
        print('token', token)
        if token:
            try:
                profile = Profile.objects.get(token=token)
            except:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(profile, data=request.data)
        reply={}
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            profile = serialized_data.save(user=request.user)
            reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile, many=False).data
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serialized_data.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

With your code, i get This QueryDict instance is immutable error

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard to use the `PUT` request method for updating in your current code and situation it is better to use the `ProfileSerializer` since it has more fields. Also, the way I see it you only have three fields in the User object that can be changed and those three fields I assume is rarely changed.

**views.py**

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    update a profile
    """
    data = request.data
    print data
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(token=data.get('token'))
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(profile, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'height', 'weight', 'token')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        first_name = data.pop('first_name', None)
        last_name = data.pop('last_name', None)
        data = super(ProfileSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        data['first_name'] = first_name
        data['last_name'] = last_name
        return data

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name', None)
        last_name = validated_data.pop('last_name', None)
        user_inst_fields = {}
        if first_name:
            user_inst_fields['first_name'] = first_name
        if last_name:
            user_inst_fields['last_name'] = last_name
        if user_inst_fields:
            User.objects.update_or_create(pk=instance.user.id,
                                          defaults=user_inst_fields)
        profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
            token=instance.token, defaults=validated_data)
        return profile
```

Simply just set the user to read only for it to avoid validation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to update the user but only the profile of the user like weight, height, complexion, location etc. How can i do so with APIView?

Comment: Using ProfileSerializer, i can update the profile but can i update the username, first_name, last_name and email either?

Comment: I have updated my question with your code. I get an error of This QueryDict instance is immutable and also in get i dont see the first_name, last_name which is defined in to_internal_value.

Comment: Can  you comment an example of the data being sent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143012/discussion-between-apprentice-and-dean-christian-armada).

Comment: (u'request data', <QueryDict: {u'complexion': [u'2'], u'weight': [u'64'], u'dob': [u'1993-02-14'], u'marital_status': [u'0'], u'permanent_location': [u'Biratnagar'], u'height': [u''], u'body_type': [u'1'], u'create_profile_for': [u'0'], u'gender_status': [u'M'], u'current_location': [u'Kathmandu'], u'about_me': [u'']}>)

Comment: first_name, last_name are not shown so that might be creating error when updating the profile because data has no first_name and last_name