# one url for views with id and not with id

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Is there a way to use only one url for the views to display the content with id(token) and without id(token). For example there is a view which displays the list of profile of user if token is not provided otherwise show a specific user with the token that is passed.

Here is a view

```
def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
      """
      Returns a list of profile of user or single user if token is provided
      """
      reply={}
      try:
          profile_instance = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
          if token:
              profile = profile_instance.get(token=token)
              reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile).data
          else:
              reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(profile_instance, many=True).data
      except:
          reply['data']=[]
      return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The url wil be something like this

```
url(
      r'^users/$',
      views.UserList.as_view(),
      name="user_list"
  ),
url(
   r'^users/(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+)$',
   views.UserList.as_view(),
   name="user_profile"
),
```

Is there a way to have only one url?

Comment: You have to use viewsets in django rest framework for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is a way. Just make the `token` url parameter optional. Like this:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+)?$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
```

Notice the trailing `?`, which means 0 or 1 matches of the `token`. If the `token` is provided then it'll be the value provided (obviously!). If not, it will be `None`.

Comment: can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702531/confusion-on-which-serializer-to-use-to-update-user-profile/43702673?noredirect=1 question? i have a full code on https://pastebin.com/Bepe9fFd too for user profile update along with first_name, last_name and username of user.